# Empty answer if an initial zero is not found

Tags: regex, ruby

When I run a regex trying to remove an initial zero from a number as in the example I get the correct answer if there is a zero before the number. However, if there are no zeroes I get an empty string.

This is not the expected result for me, but might be the way things work.

I would like to have an expression that keeps the string intact if there are no initial zeroes.

This is MRI Ruby 2.6.1

Example 1

```
string = "0067 more text"
puts string[0..3].sub!(/^0+/, "")
#=> 67
```

Example 2

```
string = "6776 more text"
puts string[0..3].sub!(/^0+/, "")
#=> 'empty string'
```

In Example 2 I would like it to keep the string intact. I wouldn't a priori expect the expression to delete the string. But if it is the correct behaviour I need a way to make it keep the original string intact.

Comment: Did you try `^0*` to match 0 or more times a zero.

Answer (score 1):

`sub!` does keep the string intact if there’s no match. It just *returns* `nil`. If you don’t need to do the operation in place, use the non-mutating `String#sub`:

```
puts string[0..3].sub(/^0+/, "")
```

If you do want the replacement done in place, you’ll be holding onto the string in practice, and it’ll work fine:

```
s = string[0..3]
s.sub!(/^0+/, "")
puts s
```

[Relevant documentation for `sub!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-sub-21):

> #### sub!(pattern, replacement) → str or nil
> sub!(pattern) {|match| block } → str or nil
>
> Performs the same substitution as `#sub` in-place.
>
> Returns `str` if a substitution was performed or `nil` if no substitution was performed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [match](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#method-i-match) method instead of sub!

```
match(/[^0]\d+/)

string = "0067 more text"
puts string[0..3].match(/[^0]\d+/)
#=> 67

string = "6776 more text"
puts string[0..3].match(/[^0]\d+/)
#=> 6776
```